Irritating WiFi instability
I have problems with WiFi on an Acer Aspire A515-43 with Windows 11. Now and then, the WiFi connection starts behaving strange. It goes down and recovers shortly after some to some tens of seconds just to go down again. The disturbance continues for 2–6 minutes and disappears. It happens at seemingly random intervals, and I cannot associate it with any activity on the system. It may happen while the PC stays unused. I have a background app that pings the router every 3 seconds to keep WiFi busy. 
I downloaded the WiFi driver from the Acer homepage, but it has the same version as the one I'm using, so it wouldn't install. The PC is several years old, but the WiFi problem started some weeks ago. I had reinstalled Windows, and I think it started afterwards. But the initial Windows 11 was upgraded from Windows 10; it wasn't the OEM's installation.
I have other devices on the same WiFi network, in particular a streaming TV, and they show no disturbances.
What more can I check on the system?
Since I've developed the app to activate and monitor WiFi, I could add more checks, e.g., the CPU temperature and other health indices. Where can I find the Win32 API for such functions?

Try another IS froim USB, e.g., Ubuntu Live. If the PC connects well on another OS, you know it's Windows.

@DrMoishe Pippik Well, I've written, "I have other devices on the same WiFi network, in particular a streaming TV, and they show no disturbances." The TV is extremely sensitive. It stops immediately at a WiFi break. But it doesn't stop when the PC goes through the disturbance. It is a Windows problem. Or the hardware's.

That does not determine if it's hardware issues inside the PC. If another OS works, it's not hardware at fault.

@DrMoishe Pippik: Perhaps I don't understand you. The TV uses Android TV. Our phones run Android. Other PCs use Windows, but they have different hardware and different drivers. The problem occurs only on the Acer. It must be either Acer's software or hardware, I think. What other alternatives do you see?

Yes, that is correct, either Acer's software or hardware. Booting from USB differentiates between those two.

@DrMoishe Pippik: Booting from USB differentiates between those two? Do you mean that if I boot from USB, I can tell whether it is a hardware or software issue? Please explain this. The only way to boot from USB, I know, is to use the installation media. Then you have no access to drive C: except for using it for a new installation. The installation does use WiFi, but it won't tell me about WiFi problems. My app would tell, but I cannot start it.

If you boot e.g. Ubuntu live you'll be able to test whether the supposed instability occurs or not. That's the point, rule out hardware if it works fine in the live OS or rule out the installed OS if the problem persists. You don't need access to anything else other than what's loaded in RAM - the live session - but actually you have access to everything else unless encrypted but you don't need to, you're over-complicating things that are trivial troubleshooting steps .

@ChanganAuto Thank you. The disturbance occurs randomly and lasts for 2–6 minutes. During this period, WiFi wakes up shortly. E.g., you can use a browser, but it's lagging. If you start Ubuntu and see no lagging, it's either because you didn't hit a disturbance or because there are no disturbances under Linux. Or is there some way to come to a more definite conclusion?
